# How can I look for file paths within .conf files?

Tags: powershell

There are a lot of directories and .conf/.xml files I have to open and search through.  I have this right now:

```
$Path = "D:\Logs"

$Text = "*\log"

$PathArray = @()

$Results = "D:\Logs\Search.txt"

Get-Childitem $Path -Filter "*.conf" -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
        ForEach-Object
        {
            If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text -AllMatches)
            {
                $PathArray += $_.FullName
                $PathArray += $_.FullName
            }
        }

Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}

$PathArray | % {$_} | Out-File “D:\Logs\Search.txt”
```

I am trying to create this script, so I can have the out-file report all of the .conf files in a txt file with the correct path the .conf files are located in.  I will also do the same with the .xml files by simply replacing the .conf with .xml.  As of now, I am getting the .txt file up, but no paths.  I know I am missing one or two things but I can not figure out what it is.  I will have to manually change the old paths with the news ones I have already created. I would like to run this script to search for all the .conf/.xml files with a *\log or *\logs in them.

Comment: I can see a few issues here including a couple of redundancies. Can you include a small sample of a  .conf as it could be anything in there. What do you expect as the output? The matches it finds in the files?

Comment: Well the basic .conf file will have a path similar to "c:\apache\tomcat\bin" for logs.  Many of the log files are scattered, which is a hassle to search for them.  As for the output, I would like the path of the .conf files which contain "\log" in them.  I would like the search pattern to look for the original placement of the logs, so I can manually change them to a centralized log folder system.

Comment: One of the thing I was asking was can you include a sample of a file? So that means you want the matched lines as well?

Comment: <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                   pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

Comment: That would be a sample of the file

Comment: It would not be matched lines; however, the current log file system is scattered between multiple config, xml, properties, and etc. files.  That is why I am looking to create a script that would search with these files to determine if there is a log path within the code.  Then this script would output the file path of the files into a txt file.  Therefore, I could manually reconfigure the code with the new path I have current set up.  I did not make the current system, I am trying to centralize it.  Also I kept hitting enter in the previous comments. Sorry

Comment: So the files are _not_ all xml files? So is searching for the text "log" sufficient as you dont have fully qualified paths in that sample? and last thing. What is your Powershell version. `Get-Host`

Comment: Two things.  First, Select-String -Pattern expects a regex.  Right now your regex isn't escaping the backslash.  I think you want `$Text = '\\logs'.  There is no need for the `*`.  B, your sample file content shows `directory="logs"` - there is no backslash so the pattern won't match.  That is, assuming the sample above is of a .conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with your regex not escaping backslash and it apparently not matching what you've shown as the typically content of a .conf file. Plus it can be simplified.  Try this - adjusting the $Text regex to actually match the desired text in the .conf files:

```
$Path = "D:\Logs"
$Text = "\\log"
$Results = "D:\Logs\Search.txt"

$PathArray = @(Get-Childitem $Path -Filter *.conf -Recurse -File | 
               Where {(Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw) -match $Text})

Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray

$PathArray | Out-File $Results -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will test it out as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues. Keith got the biggest one being that `Select-String` uses regex by default. Again, you had some redundancies like adding to the `$pathArray` twice and the use of `ForEach-Object {$_}`.

I wanted to show a solution that still uses `select-string` but uses some of the switch therein to get the use you want out of it. Main one being `-simplematch` which treats the pattern literally and not as regex. I saw an underscore leading the log in your sample text so I use that here. If you don't want to or it does not match your data simply remove it.

```
$Path = "D:\Logs"
$Text = "_log"
$Results = "D:\Logs\Search.txt"

$PathArray = Get-Childitem $Path -Filter "*.conf" -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} | 
    Where-Object{Select-string $_ -Pattern $Text -SimpleMatch -Quiet} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

# Show results on screen
$PathArray

# Export results to file
$PathArray | Set-Content $Results
```